# WS Addressing and Multiple "ReplyTo"

Tags: wcf, ws-addressing

Please any one clarify me WS Addressing in WCF  does support the multiple ReplyTo or not?.

Answer (score 2):

This would answer your question in depth [@ Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx)

...

**Multiple Endpoints and Unique Addresses**

There are a few reasons why you might wish to expose multiple endpoints on a particular service. One reason is to expose the same contract using a few different bindings. For example, you may have some consumers that can only deal with WS-I Basic Profile 1.1-compliant services (one binding) and others that can handle the full suite of standards (another binding). Or you may have some internal enterprise consumers that demand binary TCP transmissions for performance reasons (yet another binding). The ability to expose the same contract using different bindings allows you to accommodate all of these consumers at the same time.
When exposing multiple endpoints with different bindings, each endpoint address must be unique. This is because each endpoint requires a different transport listener and channel stack. Consider the service configuration in Figure 4. In this example, all of the endpoints expose the same contract (ISimpleMath) but each one uses a different binding, so each address must be unique. If you modify an endpoint to use the same address as one of the other endpoints, Windows Communication Foundation will throw an exception while opening the ServiceHost.

...

Comment: Sorry i asked about the multiple Reply TO end point reference in SOAP.Is it possible ?.Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I assume WCF is standards compliant. In this case at most one replyTo address can be given. See [Section 3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-core/#abstractmaps) of the [WS-Addressing Core Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-core/#abstractmaps) for details.